# when try to add check box to grid view on asp.net forms i get error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, c#-5.0

I work on asp.net web forms with c# I need to add checkbox column as last column on gridview

but i don't know how to add it

```
static  string con =
   "Data Source=DESKTOP-L558MLK\\AHMEDSALAHSQL;" +
   "Initial Catalog=UnionCoop;" +
   "User id=sa;" +
   "Password=321;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con);
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GridViewSearch.DataSource = GetDataForSearch();
                GridViewSearch.DataBind();
            }

        }


        public DataTable GetDataForSearch()
        {
            string response = string.Empty;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "select top 10 datelogged AS EntredDatetime, Doc_type AS OrderType, Printer_name, BranchID AS BranchCode, id from Print_Report";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 50000;
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
            }
            return dt;

        }

on aspx page
 <asp:GridView ID="GridViewSearch" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
```

```
  GridViewSearch.DataSource = GetDataForSearch();
                DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                checkColumn.Name = "X";
                checkColumn.HeaderText = "X";
                checkColumn.Width = 50;
                checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
                checkColumn.FillWeight = 10; //if the datagridview is resized (on form resize) the checkbox won't take up too much; value is relative to the other columns' fill values
                GridViewSearch.Columns.Add(checkColumn);
                GridViewSearch.DataBind();
```

I get error on line below

```
GridViewSearch.Columns.Add(checkColumn);
```

argument 1 can't convert from system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckbox to system.web.ui.webcontrol.databoundfield

so how to solve this issue please ?

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't add the check box column in your asp markup instead?

Comment: no reason but how to add markup

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me, that if you want say a button, or check box, or dropdown?

why not just add it to the markup.

So, say like this:

```
<div id="MyGridPick" runat="server" style="display:normal;width:40%">
    <asp:Label ID="lblSel" runat="server" Text="" Font-Size="X-Large"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID"  cssclass="table table-hover" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"     />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"       />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"                />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" ItemStyle-Width="120px"     />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Then my code to load is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        SqlCommand cmdSQL = 
            new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");
        GridView1.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Now, of course I get VERY tired of typing that connection string stuff over and over. So, I have a "genreal" routine like this:

```
    public DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

And the result of running above:

[image]

So, kind of hard to make the case to "add" a check box control, when you can just drop one into the gridview.

Same goes for a button, maybe we want a button to "view" or edit the above row, or some such.

So, once again, just drop in a plain jane button, say like this:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="bView" runat="server" Text="View" CssClass="btn"
                        OnClick="bView_Click" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

And now we have this:

[image]

And EVEN better?

Well, since that button (or check box) is a plain jane standard control?

then you can add standard events, like a click event, or whatever you want.

Say this code for the button click (shows how to get current row).

```
protected void bView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    GridViewRow gRow = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    int PKID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];

    SqlCommand cmdSQL = 
        new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @ID");
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PKID;

    DataTable dtHotel = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
    General.FLoader(MyEditArea, dtHotel.Rows[0]);

    MyGridPick.Style.Add("display", "none");        // hide grid
    MyEditArea.Style.Add("display", "normal");      // show edit div area

}
```

And we now get/see this:

[image]

## Edit: Process each checked/selected row.

this:

```
protected void cmdSelProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // process all rows in GV with check box

    String sPK = "";
    List<int> MySelected = new List<int>();
    foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkSel = (CheckBox)gRow.FindControl("chkSel");
        if (chkSel.Checked)
        {
            int PK = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];
            // add pk value of row to our list
            MySelected.Add(PK);
            // Or we could process data based on current gRow
            if (sPK != "")
                sPK += ",";

            sPK += PK.ToString();
            Debug.Print(PK.ToString());
        }

    }
    // at this point, we have a nice list of selected in MySelected
    // or, maybe process as a data table

    SqlCommand cmdSQL =
        new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA where ID IN({sPK})");

    DataTable rstSelected = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
    // 
    foreach (DataRow dr in rstSelected.Rows)
    {
        // do whatever
    }

}
```

Comment: yes working but small thing i need how to loop and access id from button

Comment: Which iD, the row for the button click? See the added example code - it shows how on the simple button click, you can get the PK id. Note how the ID is hidden, not included in the gv, but the button click can use that PK. This is done by using the datakeys feature - take close look at gridview markup - note Datakeys="ID" is the key as to how this was done.

Comment: See the NEW extra edit - I show how to grab, get, process the rows selected.

Answer (score 0):

Datagridviewcheckboxcolumn is a Windows formx object. You are working in web forms. Please see the link below for information on the [webforms check box field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxfield?view=netframework-4.8.1)

```
    CheckBoxField checkColumn = new CheckBoxField();
```